# Best way to convert pdf to greyscale with php?

Tags: php, tcpdf, grayscale

If I want to convert a pdf to greyscale whats the best way to go about it. Im currently using tcpdf to convert html to pdf but I also need an option where I can convert it to greyscale. Whats the best way to go about doing this.

Comment: I think this is not going to be trivial, if possible at all. Is this about text or images as well? Can you use and install external tools? What platform is this on?

Comment: Will you be using static CSS or will the HTML/CSS input be completely dynamic? In the first case you could just create a "grayscale" version of the CSS and provide the correct CSS data when processing the HTML (and will only have to convert images to grayscale). For the latter case you will have to preprocess the HTML/CSS to convert all colors & images to grayscale.

Comment: Yeh It is a little awkward Im going to mess about with it and see what I can come up with, everyones comments I will take into account and I will post an answer up at some point on my findings.

Answer (score 4):

If you have [Imagick](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) (imagemagick) installed, you can take your generated PDF and save another gray-scaled one.

```
$image = new Imagick('generatedPDF.pdf');
$image->setColorspace(imagick::COLORSPACE_GRAY);
$image->writeImage('newPic.pdf');
$image->clear();
$image->destroy();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to manipulate the HTML and images and make the HTML grayscale *before* converting to PDF.

You can run through all your images and pass them through GD to make them all gray
http://php.about.com/od/gdlibrary/ss/grayscale_gd.htm

You will also need to probably create a separate css to use in case you have color applied to your page.

HTH