# black and white 300 dpi pdf output in dompdf

Tags: php, dompdf, dpi

I'm using dompdf for generating pdf with php.

The generated output is **300 DPI, 24 bit color**.

I need output as **300 DPI, Black and White color**.

Is it possible to achieve in dompdf?

I'm in trouble. If anybody have solved this issue before please help me.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK a pdf as such cannot be set to be black and white. There are two possible options:

1. Create a stylesheet which renders your page in black and white. This stylesheet could also be used to provide users with a print view of the page.
2. Use [ImageMagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) to convert your pdf to black and white after creation. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5090397/best-way-to-convert-pdf-to-greyscale-with-php) for reference.